# String declaration VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: android, variables, declaration

i have problem in this simple code, I declare a String , and want change it inside onCreate but AFTER onCreate i have "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" Error !!
And if i put item=222 inside onCreate i get "111null333" when Toast display
here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static String item;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mStrings[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    item="222";

    private String[] mStrings={
            "111"+item+"333",
            "test"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please spend some time and format your question correctly ? i do not see clearly if the item = "222"; is inside a method or not.

But if your formatting is "correct" then your problem is that the assignation of a value to the item variable can not be done outside of a method or the static{} block of code. And so if you use the item variable in another object or class variable before assigning it a value it will be the default value (null for objects and 0 or false for the primitive values).

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static String item;
    private String[] mStrings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        item = "222";
        mStrings = new String[2];
        mStrings[0] = "111" + item + "333";
        mStrings[1] = "test";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mStrings[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Even if i put item='222" inside onCreate, i get null value when i use it in mString array !!!

Comment: did you read the last part of my comment ? let me add an example so that you can see it clearly.

Comment: Ok, i added the example, as you can see, to use the item variable first you need to assign it a value, and then it will have something different than NULL, cause all the object and class variable declarations are done in the "same" step, and thus you can not assign a value that will be set later on the execution process (onCreate).

Comment: Thank you, it works great, and thanks for making things clear about how assigning works in OO :)

Comment: your welcome. I hope this can help other people with the same problem.