# setImageBitmap gets Syntax Errors

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to take a Bitmap and display it in an ImageView.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/res/drawable/" + imageFileName);
iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

That's my code for it. I create an ImageView and a Bitmap. I want to display my Bitmap in my ImageView. But I always get these two errors on the `iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);` statment

```
Syntax error on token "bMap", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token    
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Does anybody has an idea why this happens and what i have to change?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716378/string-declaration-variabledeclaratorid-expected-after-this-token) link help you and this will be a true answer.

Comment: Why you using decodeFile? You should use `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.example);` if you have a picture name like example.jpg/png in your res/drawable folder.

Comment: Furthermore `/res/drawable` does not point inside your apk but to the whole file system. So guaranteed not to work (as intended).

Comment: As this is a syntax error check for misplaced curly braces.

Comment: @JoeyChong I am making a picture in this program and want to display it at this point, this picture has a timestamp so i cant write this for one picture only

Comment: @EugenPechanec I already checked 50 times, there are no braces missing

Comment: Is "bMap" already defined perhaps? Did you try clean & build? What is your IDE? Can you try opening the file in a different IDE?

Comment: If you are using a dynamic generated picture, then you shouldn't put the picture at `/res/drawable` folder. That is for static picture and it will generate an id at R class.

Comment: @EugenPechanec its the first and only time i use bMap and its not defined before. I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers with and Android SDK  plugin, i haven't tried opening it with a differnt IDE. What are you using?

Comment: @Tim I've been using Android Studio for some time now, there's a stable release out. The compile times are a bit worse than in eclipse then again it's easier (and more power consuming) to build multi-flavor apps or use annotations... Anyway can you post the whole file here or on pastebin?

Comment: @EugenPechanec http://pastebin.com/UR4Dy2AM here a like to the whole activity...there is anotherone where i make the picture and save it in a file too but everthing is alride there

Answer (score 0):

In OP's [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/UR4Dy2AM) I've found the following snippet:

```
String imageFileName =getIntent().getStringExtra("imageFileName");
//String bildquelle = "R.drawable." + imageFileName;

public class ImageChange extends Activity {          
  ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
  String bildquelle = "R.drawable." + imageFileName;
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier(bildquelle, "drawable", getPackageName());

  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
  //Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/res/drawable/" + imageFileName);
  iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this including:

1. The code is not inside a method body.
2. The code is a `Activity` subclass.
3. The code improperly calls `getResources().getIdentifier(...)`.

Instead of the above code I suggest MERGING the rest of activity with the following:

```
public class BildAnzeigen extends ActionBarActivity {

  ImageView iv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bild_anzeigen);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view); // replace the id with the one from layout definition

    handleIntent(getIntent());
  }

  private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String imageFileName = intent.getStringExtra("imageFileName");
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", null);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
  }
}
```

Note: This will not work if the images are not compiled within your apk. There's no way to add anything to drawables after building. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: ok thx that really helped me out...how can I do it with a picture from the SDcard from which I know the name and the path?

Comment: @Tim see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662279/why-am-i-getting-incorrect-phone-and-sdcard-memory-information/27662469#27662469 you have to use this approach because the location of sd card varies across devices. It may be `/sdcard`, `/storage/sdcard1`, etc.